# How do they create that hovering Text that stays still according to scene when camera is moving

Tags: film-techniques, production

In the start of this video you will see "Salmon Raju" .. That is text that looks is staying still according to the location in the scene but the camera is still moving around.

I can understand simply watermarking movies, which I see during the start of movie when showing cast names etc, but I am curious how they do the first thing I asked.

If you have seen Indian Premier League matches you would have notices they many a times show a Player's score and Runs to Win and some other things in the middle of ground that is staying still but the camera is moving around the ground.

How do they do it?

I am a Software Engineer but unable to figure it out, any answers with technical/non-technical explanations are welcomed.

Comment: My best guess is something like Adobe After Effects, I've seen it done in movies too and I've wondered about this myself.

Comment: No No ... I have seen it in Live cricket matches too ...

Comment: I think its a simple transparent overlay which can be keyed to landmarks in the frame.

e.g. at the start of the video, it will be tracking the buildings.

in a live sports match, it will be keyed to markings on the pitch or around the arena.

The expensive versions can even create a virtual mask so the text/image "disappears" behind things.

Comment: @Tim good pick ... in the live match that text must be tied to the pitch ... :P

Comment: @Tim That's a pretty accurate description of what happens. It's pretty much how they key any CGI to a moving frame. Pick reference points, tie the CGI to the same points and the software tracks it automatically.

Comment: Good point.  Yes, in the US they do something similar (show stats, player photos, etc...) during live Football broadcasts and make it appear as if they're actually on the field.

Comment: @JohnnyBones yeah ... I also see those texts in the ground (not in air) so players are moving above them making it look like that text is painted on the ground

Comment: @JohnnyBones - that's a combination of keying the cgi to a moving frame, with chromakey added so that the graphic overlays anything the colour of the grass/turf.

Comment: I think that one of the best examples of this is in *Zombieland*. Here's an interesting tutorial on how it can be done: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6HPvGYA9HBc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This effect is usually referred to as 'motion tracking'. Motion tracking involves tracking certain points on objects within the original video and applying the movement of this tracking to a new object or piece of text added in post production. Objects can be tracked on all 3 axis with modern programs.

[Adobe After Effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_After_Effects), as mentioned, is just one of a handful of these programs and is widely used throughout the film industry to accomplish such effects. [Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AmS0coiXy1Y) an example of just how quick it is to achieve.

At a basic level, motion tracking allows you to add 2D and 3D text to a scene. However, highly skilled animators and editing crew can use this fundamental technique to create complex virtual, (but realistic looking) scenes using other 3D software, 3DS Max coupled with Boujou for example. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yjj7E8QLuPU) is a video showing examples of tracking a real scene and adding in the virtual scene in post production.